# WPF button contentproperty issue

Tags: wpf-controls

I have created a custom control deriving from Button in WPF. I have overriden DefaultStyleKeyProperty and then set dependency property for Content. This control has its own style for OnMouseEnter, OnMouseLeave , OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp. When used, the events and customized styles appear but content is not shown. How do i set the content?

The control's code is below:

```
public class SymbolButton : Button
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty;
        static SymbolButton()
        {
           DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SymbolButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SymbolButton)));
           FrameworkPropertyMetadata metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata();
           metadata.AffectsArrange = true;
           ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Content",
                            typeof(string), typeof(SymbolButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        }
        Point startPoint = new Point(0.5, 0);
        Point endPoint = new Point(0.5, 1);
        public string Content
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public SymbolButton()
        {
            //this.Content = "Symbol";
            ButtonDefaultDisplay();
            this.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3.3);
            this.FontSize = 21;
            this.FontStyle = FontStyles.Oblique;
        }

        private void ButtonDefaultDisplay()
        {
            this.Foreground = Brushes.BlueViolet;
            this.Background = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.LightBlue,
                                                        Colors.MediumAquamarine,
                                                        startPoint, endPoint);
            this.BorderBrush = Brushes.DarkTurquoise;
        }

        private void ButtonClickDisplay()
        {
            this.Foreground = Brushes.LightCyan;
            this.Background = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.MidnightBlue,
                                                       Colors.DarkTurquoise,
                                                       startPoint, endPoint);
            this.BorderBrush = Brushes.Cyan;
        }

        private void ButtonHighlight()
        {
            this.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            this.Background = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.MistyRose,
                                                       Colors.LightBlue,
                                                       endPoint, startPoint);
            this.BorderBrush = Brushes.Plum;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonClickDisplay();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonHighlight();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonHighlight();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonDefaultDisplay();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to post the default style of your control too. Also how you use it in your xaml.

Comment: Thank you Xin. I found that because i hadn't placed ContentPresenter in generic.xaml, the button content wasn't displayed. As for the usage of this control, i just add it to MainWindow. SymbolButton actually represents a calculator symbol button. I am learning customization in WPF, so started with custom buttons. Is there anyway the ContentPresenter can be programmatically set in above code?? If we have to use xaml, there is no difference in using CustomControl in WPF and customising the control template using styles right??

Comment: I think you should just create a SymbolButtonStyle Style.